# Firefox top padding difference (comparing to other browsers)

Tags: html, css, firefox

I haven't found a clear solution for this problem, so I decided to create this topic. There is a very annoying Firefox feature:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div{
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        width: 31px;
        height: 50px;
        font: 15px Verdana;
        background: #0F0;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div>test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result (200%):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjqP7.jpg]

As you see, top padding in Firefox is bigger (6px) than top padding in other browsers (5px). 
How to solve this?

**EDIT**: any css reset doesn't fix it.

Comment: I tested this locally with FF and chrome and they were identical.

Comment: @j08691 i can see the issue in a non-normalized document, though you have to really zoom in to see the different (its very tiny). Started a fiddle with that behavior. [non-normalized code](http://jsfiddle.net/3BrPy/show/) vs [normalized code](http://jsfiddle.net/3BrPy/1/show/).

Comment: Unfortunately I can still see this 1px difference in both cases :(

Comment: Do you want to remove the space around the green background or some thing else you want, because i am not able to see the image. Image is not showing its showing enter image description here.

Comment: @Happy Singh - please check the image now.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually the case when there is no default value normalization being done in your css, which is why such tools such as the [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) and the [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheets have come about. Such tools try to normalize and reset the default values set by the user agents (browsers).

Comment: @Jack Looks fine to me. Here is a demo of your code without using any normalization, [without normalization](http://jsfiddle.net/3BrPy/show/) here we can see your issue, and now here is the same code using the `normalize.css` stylesheet, [normalized demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BrPy/1/show/) and everything looks the same across browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately I can still see this 1px difference in both cases :(

Comment: @Jack what browsers are you using and are your zoom levels correct on both browsers? I'm on FF10.0.2 and Chrome18 beta and i can see the pixel difference, though when the css is normalized its gone.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 10.0.2 and up-to-date versions of IE, Chrome and Opera. Zoom is correct.

Comment: @Jack Are your font-sizes set to the default in your browser? No custom fonts settings being set? I get the same results as you do but when the css is normalized it is fixed, we can't be getting different results on something so simple :P

Comment: Tested it on my test box and got the same as well, normalized css looks good and i get your issue on the non-normalized fiddle.

Comment: Well, apparently we do can - I reinstalled Firefox (clean, newest version) and the problem hadn't gone away. Anyway, what part from normalization code fixes the issue for you? Do you know?

Comment: Line 1 mainly of the normalize.css stylesheet does the work. Remember, normalization does not begin with your element, it starts with the higher level tags. Eric Meyer's [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) sheet does the main bulk of that work, study the source so you can see how it is all reset back to 0.

Comment: Well, you haven't said anything I didn't know. Some line from the normalization file does the job for you. So again: do you know what concrete line (or lines) does the job? I can't study the file for the answer, because it simply doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Jack line 1 of the normalization.css sheet, its available there. In line 6 in Eric Meyer's reset sheet you can find the reset values also. You have a special case where i can't go beyond your code, so test in another machine or check your code in a new (clean) profile in your browsers because i can't diagnose your issue past that point.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help. I have to move on, beacause I've already wasted too much time for this problem (shame on you, Firefox). Maybe someone will find the solution in the future. Anyway, again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try yui-reset.  It can remedy problems like these and other differing default behavior across browsers.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 0):

put this on top of your css:

```
 DIV {  /*let Firefox stick to the padding web standards*/
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
```